# Idiomatic French expression for "blossom into (a star)" or "rise to become (a top player)"

Tags: expressions, anglais, allemand

> En seulement une année, elle est **devenue** le n°1 de l’équipe !

Here I'm looking for a French  expression (a commonly used, idiomatic one) to convey the idea of "sich entwickeln" in German. The "sich entwickeln" is more than just a neutral "**devenir**/**become**" and close to "**blossom into** (a star)" or "**rise to become** (a top player)".

I would say the phrasing above, for lack of a better expression that comes to mind, but it will most likely come across as lacklustre, compared to the idea conveyed by "sich entwickeln".

Answer (score 3):

"Blossom" is close to *s'épanouir* and "rise to become" might be translated by *s'imposer* or *s'affirmer* giving:

> *En une année seulement, elle s'est épanouie et [s'est] imposée* (or *affirmée*) *comme numéro un de l'équipe.*

Here is a [quote from *France Football*](https://www.francefootball.fr/news/Angleterre-hugo-lloris-un-gardien-epanoui-a-tottenham/651108) using both of these expressions:

> Angleterre : Hugo Lloris, un gardien épanoui à Tottenham
>   Au fil des saisons, Hugo Lloris s'est imposé comme un des meilleurs gardiens de Premier League.

Comment: Is this phrasing fit for colloquial use?

Comment: *S'épanouir* and *s'imposer* can be used in any context, *s'affirmer* is more formal.

Comment: I believe that "s'imposer comme" is the best way to translate what the OP is looking for and is enough per se. I don't think you need to add "s'est épanouie et ..." before ("blossom into" was just an example) as it makes the whole expression a bit clumsy (IMO), especially if you compare it with the sole verb "sich entwickeln".

Answer (score 2):

A common idiomatic phrasing you may consider is “se hisser au premier rang”, although “s'affirmer” probably has better-matched connotations relating to self-development.

Answer (score 1):

J'aurais employé l'expression "gagner ses galons" :

> En seulement une année, elle aura gagné ses galons au sein de l'équipe [pour en devenir le numéro 1].

Je mets une partie la phrase entre crochet qui bien que pas nécessaire pour faire passer l'idée apporte quand-même une précision supplémentaire...